# how split audio file in multiple chapters with predefined times

Tags: awk, sed, ffmpeg

how split audio book file with  in 10 chapters easier to listen , with given metadata predefined times
0.000000, 3472.683000 seconds this ch0

3472.683000, 7642.058000  ch1

etc..

2 columns the begin and end of each chapter,

i'm dummy but tried and failed with awk to add columns right and left to obtain the command line

```
    ffmpeg -i output.mp3  -acodec copy -ss  begin -to end  ch'number'.mp3.
```

the problemn with the NF position and then increment numbers of new output files

how to use awk or sed and count new file names ch01 ch02 etc

Answer (score 0):

'begin' and 'end' time of each predefined  chapter , purpose: 10 ffmpeg command line to split them

```
    ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3  -acodec copy -ss begin to end  ch'number'.mp3
```

first add at the beginning the pattern '-i output.mp3  -acodec copy -ss' with sed

```
    sed  -e '1,$s/^/ -i audiofile.mp3  -acodec copy -ss' file1 > file2 #file1 :contains 2 columns of begin and end time
```

the result

```
    -i audiofile.mp3  -acodec copy -ss begin, end
```

second replace the ',' by '-to' globally with g

```
    sed s'/, / -to /g' file2 > file3
```

we will have

```
    -i audiofile.mp3  -acodec copy -ss begin -to end
```

Third increment counter with awk

```
    awk '{$(NF+1) = "ch"(NR-1)".mp3"} 1' file3 > file4
```

we obtain ch0.mp3 ch1.mp3 ..ch10.mp3

```
     -i audiofile.mp3 -acodec copy -ss begin -to end ch'number'.mp3
```

ffmpeg read input from file4

```
    ffmpeg $(cat file4)
```

you will have 10 chapters

Answer (score 0):

The segment muxer is meant for this.

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp3 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 0,3472.683,7642.058 -segment_start_number 1 ch%d.mp3
```

I've added the first three chapter times. This command will create ch1.mp3, ch2.mp3, ch3.mp3.

Comment: the title of audio book is interesting too: the Coders of Clive Thompson .so to be more clear these are the f first chapters obtained in file4as exlpained below
-i output.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 0.000000 -to 3472.683000 ch0.mp3
-i output.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 3472.683000 -to 7642.058000 ch1.mp3
-i output.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 7642.058000 -to 11130.578000 ch2.mp3
-i output.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 11130.578000 -to 14836.993000 ch3.mp3
-i output.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 14836.993000 -to 18700.283000 ch4.mp3
sure you have improvements to save time